# Distribute iOS static Library

Tags: ios, static

I have compiled 2 static libs of same code-base, one for simulator and one for device. I would like to know, whether should i submitted both libs to Apple.

Or can I create a universal static lib, which can run on both Simulator as well on Device. Is it recommended by Apple to  submit only universal library ? How can I produce that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "submit libs to Apple"? You can only submit complete applications, not components.

Answer (score 0):

Apples don't care about code for iOS simulator and thats shy when you build application for submit, binary for i386 architecture won't be compiled by default and that's correct behavior. Just build for device and submit it, everything will be OK.